# Como acumular suma por fechas y mes

Tags: sql

buenas tardes tengo este query en SQL

```
 SELECT PERIODO,
        FECHAGESTION,
        SUM(NROCLIENTESPORDIA)CLIENTES,
        SUM(SUM(NROCLIENTESPORDIA))OVER (ORDER BY FECHAGESTION asc) as ACUMULADO  
 FROM [ConsolidadoxDia]  
 GROUP BY PERIODO,FECHAGESTION
```

El problema es como hacer para que cuando comience un nuevo mes vuelva a sumar de manera acumulada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

muy agradecido por la ayuda

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Al parecer `PERIODO` hace referencia al año y al mes (aunque es redundante, porque eso puedes obtenerlo desde la columna `FECHAGESTION`). Si agrupas solamente por `PERIODO` debería funcionar: `GROUP BY PERIODO` y, si quieres optimizar, puedes prescindir de esa columna y agrupar por año y mes de `FECHAGESTION`. Por cierto, conviene que indiques siempre con que SGBD estás trabajando: SQLServer, MySQL, Postgresql, Oracle, etc.

Comment: Hola, estoy usando como sgbd SQL server, y lo que quiero en si ,es acumular la cantidad de clientes por dia(fechagestion) ,el periodo es relativo, el problema es cuando empieza  otro mes este me sigue acumulando ejemplo 31 -01 con 01-02  , donde 01-02 debe empezar de nuevo a acumular la cantidad de clientes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas agregar una partición. En este caso, además tienes que agregar funciones para que particione por año y mes.

```
 SELECT PERIODO,
        FECHAGESTION,
        SUM(NROCLIENTESPORDIA)CLIENTES,
        SUM(SUM(NROCLIENTESPORDIA))OVER ( PARTITION BY YEAR( FECHAGESTION), 
                                                       MONTH( FECHAGESTION) 
                                           ORDER BY FECHAGESTION asc) as ACUMULADO  
 FROM [ConsolidadoxDia]  
 GROUP BY PERIODO,FECHAGESTION
```

Comment: muchas gracias agradezco tu tiempo. con ello he podido solucionar mi problemita.

Answer (score 0):

Hola te recomiendo leer el siguiente artículo donde se explica de manera detalle el cálculo de acumulados con Sql. https://data0808.com/r/82y

Comment: Saludos @JulioCorreaArchivold, las respuestas que son solo enlaces se consideran de baja calidad puesto que estas mismas podrían desaparecer a futuro convirtiéndose en enlaces muertos, por lo mismo es muy importante que se agreguen las partes importantes de éste y simplemente luego dejas el enlace como referencia. ;)